# Invalid data type error on create table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Create table image_media_tracking (
    image_rowid_src ROWID,
    image_id NUMBER(6), 
    image_src BLOB,
    image_time sysdate
);
```

Comment: `Sysdate` isn't a data type. Use `date`

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comment, use `date` instead of `sysdate`.

Also if you want column to be sysdate by default, use

```
Create table image_media_tracking (
    image_rowid_src ROWID,
    image_id NUMBER(6), 
    image_src BLOB,
    image_time date default sysdate
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`sysdate` is not an Oracle datatype (it is the function that returns the current date and time).

You need `date`, or one of the other date time datatypes.

Comment: The question specifies Oracle.  The `DATE` datatype includes both date and time elements.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need the time instead of date so use use `Datetime` rather.

Comment: What is the advantage of Datetime rather than just using date here ?

Comment: The question specifies Oracle.  The `DATE` datatype includes both date and time elements.